# Meaning of "Redirects are always followed"

Tags: ios, urlsession

I was reading a [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_in_the_background) and got a question.

What does "**Redirects are always followed**" mean in `Comply with Background Transfer Limitations`  section?

I'm still learning english, so I have no idea about what the sentence literally means exactly in that context(I do know `Redirect`, by the way).
And that seems not to be relevant to "background transfer limitation" so far.

Can you explain the sentence with simple scenario or any materials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a URL is accessed, the server can send a *redirect* response that indicates that the resource has moved.  For example, if you access `http://www.example.com` the server may send a redirect response indicating that the url `http://example.com` should be used.

For non-background URL sessions, the `URLSessionDelegate` method [`urlSession(_:task:willPerformHTTPRedirection:newRequest:completionHandler:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411626-urlsession) is called when a redirect response is received.  In this delegate method you can decide whether to follow the redirection, redirect to some other URL or reject the redirection and fail with an error.

For background URL sessions this method is not called and the redirection is always followed.

In this case "Comply with Background Transfer Limitations" means that you cannot rely on any logic in that delegate method; the limitation is that the transfer must work with redirections being followed.

Comment: Thanks. So I can't reject the redirect or do anything when it happened on background. Just follow it. Right?